# Dynamically added Camel routes not appearing in InflightExchange

Tags: java, apache-camel

I added a route dynamically to an existing CamelContext,

```
exchange.getContext().addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("sftp://...")
        .routeId("test-dy-route")
        ...
        .to("file://...");
    }

});
```

When I try to get the **number of inflight exchanges** of this route, it returns **zero**. For the same route, the status is returned correctly, i.e., "STARTED"

```
ServiceStatus status = context.getRouteStatus("test-dy-route");
int inflightExchanges = context.getInflightRepository().size("test-dy-route");
```

Did a watch over the context object on runtime (using Eclipse), it didn't have the route "" in **InflightRepository** associated with it. Not sure, what could be the reason. Meanwhile, I can see an exchange being processed on this route in the logs. I need the no of inflight exchanges to stop the route as per requirements.

EDIT: It is not actually an issue, but expected behavior as unless the remote file from the ftp server has been downloaded (using localWorkDirectory option), the route won't proceed further and hence the resource is not yet considered as an **inflight exchange**.

So, the next problem is, how to detect if the component is downloading a file?

Comment: I think you are looking for completed exchanges not inflight exchanges.

Comment: @soilworker : No, I need inflight exchanges to avoid shutting down a route in between.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to detect when the FTP component is downloading, you can try to enable the `streamDownload` option (see the [component page](http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html)). This way, as long as File component is reading the stream it should be considered an inflight exchange.

Comment: Yes, this seems a viable option. I missed it. Will have to test it though if it fits my requirement. Moreover, I found a way to get pending exchanges by getting the consumer from the route context and get the inflightExchangeSize. Thanks.